# Add Multiple markers on Artem Google Maps

Tags: c#, google-maps

I want to show multiple markers on based of longitudes and latitudes in [artem google maps](http://googlemap.codeplex.com/). currently i can show only one address based on longitude and latitude on map.

I am using an xml file to store the latitude and longitude

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Mark>
  <Position>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Latitude>37.2808</Latitude>
    <Longitude>49.5832</Longitude>
    <Name>A</Name>
</Position>
</Mark>
```

I use this code

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Map.xml"));
var query = from st in xmlDoc.Descendants("Position")
                        select st;

    foreach (var p in query)
    {
          Marker mark = new Marker();
                    mark.Position = new LatLng(double.Parse(p.Element("Latitude").Value), double.Parse(p.Element("Longitude").Value));
                    mark.Title = p.Element("Name").Value;
                    mark.Info = p.Element("Name").Value;
                    GoogleMap1.Markers.Add(mark);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a list of markers on your maps ... you just need to find the way how to read them from you xml to proper form below..., you also have some other options in Marker constuctor...

```
List<Marker> markers = new List<Marker>()
{
    new Marker { Position = new LatLng(42.1229, 24.7879), Title="A" },
    new Marker { Position =  new LatLng(42.7, 23.3), Title="B" },
    new Marker { Position =  new LatLng(43.1, 22.3), Title="C" }
};

GoogleMap1.Markers.AddRange(markers);
```